# Capturing System audio output

Tags: macos, audio, kernel, core-audio

If I'm right you cant submit apps to the mac app store if the app depends on a kext. What I'm trying to do is to capture audio output from the selected output device in System Preferences->Sound, pass it through my application which does some audio processing and outputs the audio back to the default output device. Is that functionality possible to achieve with Core Audio HAL layer only without writing a custom audio device driver that appears as a selectable device in the Sound preferences?

Comment: Sound Siphon is the only one (to my poor knowledge) that can capture sound without a kext. It actually installs a driver in /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL . I do not know how it works, but it is definitely possible.

Comment: what iterests me if you can't upload apps with kext to the store how app 'boom 2' got approved to the store which definitely uses a custom kext device driver for capturing system audio since I have it installed

Comment: That is a question to ask to the Mac App Store team and, why not, submit it to famous journals like MacWorld.